# finding a threshold with minimum tries and limited search point

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization

I would like to find a threshold with minimum number of tires;
Let's say: I have an apartment with 120 floors and we have a piece of glass. I would like to find in which floor the glass will break if we throw it. In other word, we want to find threshold floor where the glass starts breaking. In this respect, we can use binary search that returns best result. (`binary log120=7` tries) but binary search can break 6 glasses to find it.
Considering we have only two glasses and want to find a threshold floor, what is the optimum solution that minimise number of tries?

I should add that, when we have only two glasses, we can only break one and with the other one should find the exact threshold. If we use binary search, in the worst case we have 60 attempts (if the threshold is floor 59, we spare the first on floor 60, then start from floor 1 to 59). Better way is throwing the first glass in each 10 floors. In the worst case, we have 20 attempts (the threshold is floor 119, 11 attempts with the first glass and 9 attempt with the second).

Can you improve the number of attempts?

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted. I think it is a very good metaphorical description of a search problem. You got my upvote

Comment: If you have only two glasses and you want to save one so in that case you have to go one by one from first - second- third- forth floors yes tries will increase but you will save your resource. You can consider this as performance versus resource situation which we generally have in any algorithm where either you have to give more resources to get it done in give time or you can do depending upon given resource.:)

Comment: @FishySwede , actually I have optimization problem for my algorithm. Harry , yes the whole purpose to find optimum solution. later I want to generalize the model if we have more sources (e.g. 3 glasses or more up to 6)

Comment: Well can you relate it to interpolation search?

Comment: This problem is commonly referred to as [egg problem](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/egg-problem/). There are a few variants with different assumptions on how many eggs you have and the complexity of number of tries.